# How to configure freeradius to update clientsecrets if there is a update in Postgres database?

Tags: freeradius

I have configured freeradius with Postgres. On freeradius startup it loads clients and secrets from database using client-query but any updates in the database doesn't get reflected. Once I restart freeradius...the new changes gets updated in radius server.